# Jquery ajax, upload image through ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm using this plugin to upload image http://www.finalwebsites.com/demos/php_ajax_upload_example.php

But this is not working. I get an error but it is vanishing immediately in firebug

How can I make it to work? Can any one show the plugin working in jsfiddle?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: How about you first providing a jsfiddle with your non-working script so that we can see what's wrong with it and fix it?

Comment: show us how do you use the plugin

Comment: Without an error or even any of your code this is going to be next to impossible to diagnose. There is example code on the plugin link - does yours match this?

Comment: @Michael Swan :How do i upload a file to jsfiddle?

Comment: @user1115921, you don't upload files to jsfiddle. You write scripts, markup and styles. You may checkout the help section: http://doc.jsfiddle.net/ for more information.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov :I've to link two libs to make that plug in to work.How do i attach them?

Comment: @user1115921, there's an `Add Resources` button in the left which allows you to specify the url (must be publicly visible) of the plugins that your code require.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov :Here is the link http://jsfiddle.net/y8VgA/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about that plugin or how to upload a file by ajax but this is the way I've accomplished something similar after some googling.

1) Put a div on your page somewhere

```
<div id="iframeholder" style="height:0px;width:0px;display:none;"></div>
```

2) This is some jQuery that handles the upload. It appends an iframe to the div and sets it as the target of the form submission. You can then read the contents of the the iframe to see the result of the upload.

```
  thefile = $('#myfileinput').val();
  iframe = $( '<iframe name="theiframe" id="theiframe"></iframe>' );
  $('#iframeholder').append(iframe);
  $('#theuploadform').attr("action","save.php");
  $('#theuploadform').attr("method","post");
  $('#theuploadform').attr("thefile",thefile);
  $('#theuploadform').attr("enctype","multipart/form-data");
  $('#theuploadform').attr("encoding","multipart/form-data");
  $('#theuploadform').attr("target","theiframe");
  $('#theuploadform').submit(); 
  $("#theiframe").load(function() {
    iframeContents = $('#theiframe').contents().find('body').html();
    $('#theiframe').remove();
  }
```

3) This is not my proudest moment, but you need to prevent the form submitting to itself when a user presses enter on an input field which you can do by checking if the key pressed was enter and then focussing some other control. Make your selector specific to your needs here.

```
  $('input[type=text]').bind("keypress", function(thekey) {
    if(thekey.which == "13") { $('#someothercontrol').focus();return false; } 
  });
```